# T-SQL Select, ensure manager row comes before employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, import

Here is my problem. I have a table of employee data, which contains the username of the employee and their manager's username like so

```
 ______________________________________________
| employee_username | employee_manager_username|
------------------------------------------------
  tom01             |         mark2
  mark2             |         bill3
```

My question is, how can I do a select, where for any row, the row containing the employee_manager_username as the employee_username comes before ?   I guess using my example, how do I make it so that in a select, the [mark3,bill3] row comes before the [tom01,mark2] row.

Long story short, I have a 3rd party import process that warns about the manager not being found. Being able to have the manager imported before their subordinates would make the logs a little less chatty.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there records with no manager in you table? how can you tell the top level of employees?

Comment: @RomanPekar The head honcho will have himself or NULL for supervisor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I supposing that you have top level managers have employee_manager_username = null. In that case you could to recursive Common table Expression and then order by level:

```
;with CTE as (
    select t.employee_username, t.employee_manager_username, 1 as level
    from table1 as t
    where
          t.employee_manager_username is null or 
          t.employee_manager_username = t.employee_username

    union all

    select t.employee_username, t.employee_manager_username, c.level + 1 as level
    from table1 as t
        inner join CTE as c on c.employee_username = t.employee_manager_username
    where
        not (
            t.employee_manager_username is null or 
            t.employee_manager_username = t.employee_username
        )
)
select *
from CTE
order by level asc
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7619f/2) to test query

Comment: It complains that the maximum recursion limit gets hit.  When upping the limit to 32767, it takes forever to complete.  I stopped it at 1:38 of run time.

Comment: yes it could be because on top level you could have manager = user. Changed the query and added SQL fiddle example, try again

Comment: Thanks, the issue was that I have two countries in my employee list US and CAN.  The Canadian employees don't have their proper employee_manager set, so that was causing the query to misbehave.  Once I excluded them, everything worked like a charm.